# Discord.py channel detection

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am creating a discord bot and would like to know if the argument detected after the context is a channel. I tried doing this.

```
@client.command()
async def channeldetected(ctx, arg):
  if arg != channel.type:
    await ctx.send('Please mention a channel.')
```

But it didn't work. I tried looking in the discord developer docs and across stackoverflow, but could not find the answer. Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

@client.command()
async def channeldetected(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel):
    print(channel)


@channeldetected.error
async def channeldetected_error(ctx, err):
    if isinstance(err, commands.ChannelNotFound):
        await ctx.send("Please mention a channel.")
```

What is happening: `channeldetected` funtion will try to modify the `channel` argument to a `discord.TextChannel` object. If the argument can't be modified it will raise `commands.ChannelNotFound` error then in the `@channeldetected.error` function the error can be handeled. If the error is an instance of `commands.ChannelNotFound` it will send message saying "Please mention a channel.".

Answer (score 0):

To do something like this I would recommend iterating through guilds/servers channels to see if the channel's name is "arg". To do this you can use the guild attribute from ctx/context.

```
@client.command()
async def channeldetected(ctx, arg):
  guild = ctx.guild
  channel = None
  is_channel = False

  for i in guild.channels:
      if i.name == arg:
          is_channel = True
          channel = i

  print(is_channel, channel)
```

Comment: @loloToster has a way better solution for this., but if you want them not to mention a channel then this is a nice way of doing it.